# Как вывести знак % в String.format?

Tags: java, строки

Мне нужно вывести `%` в `String.format`. Но этот знак запрещён к выводу. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Смотрим в [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Conversions)

> ```
> Conversion    Argument category   Description
> '%'           percent             The result is a literal '%' ('\u0025')
> ```

Т.е. для вывода литерала "%" нужно заэкранировать его тем же служебным символом "%".

```
System.out.println(String.format("10%%")); // 10%
```

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на документацию.

Answer (score 9):

Используй %% 
Даже не знаю, что еще добавить до 30 символов сообщения

Answer (score 5):

Использование %% Вам в помощь.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class StringFormatter
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.printf(String.format("%s", "100%%"));
    }
}
```